Running headers and footers for text books
I am currently wrapping up my dissertation (double-side text book with a quite lot of math). Most information are around how you can set up a header rather than what header. While I am quite confident about the footer (I think the page number makes totally sense), I am lost on the header.
What are best practices for designing a running header (page header) and footer for text books? Are there any style guidelines how to format the header (line separator, bold, color, etc.)?

I think the only "best practice" is to make these functional and legible.
Formatting wise, I have seen headers with bananas and oranges in them, so I guess anything goes, depending on the scope of the work. Nothing wrong with looking for some inspiration, I think in your case some basic formatting should work.
